# Guardar datos en un WebView de Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, webview

Estoy intentando que la cuenta se guarde después de cerrar la app.
¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Qué intentaste? Esto podría ayudarte https://stackoverflow.com/a/32306755/13419694

Comment: Bienvenido, es demasiado importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa por favor [ask],saludos

Comment: Hola Raul, tu pregunta se parece mucho a "tengo este ejercicio, resuélvanlo", este tipo de preguntas, no suelen ser bien recibidas, te sugiero que la edites, y muestres que has intentado, para saber que formas parte de la resolución de tu problema, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.